# Custom Local Authenticator not available in Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration as shared in sample

Tags: logging, plugins, wso2, authenticator, wso2-identity-server

Referring the link: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/writing-a-custom-local-authenticator/#writing-a-custom-local-authenticator

Custom Local Authenticator not available in Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration as shared in sample document mentioned above.

I created the jar and added it in dropins folder. But it is not available in Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration as shared in sample. How can I see the logs to know the issue with jar deployment? Because the console is not showing any error. How to make sure the authenticator jar was deployed?

As discussed, please find the pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.wso2.custom.authenticator</groupId>
<artifactId>org.wso2.custom.authenticator.local</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>WSO2 Carbon - BasicAuth Custom Authenticator</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.utils</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.logging</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>scr</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>


            <version>2.3.5</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                    <Axis2Module>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</Axis2Module>
                    <Import-Package>
                        javax.servlet,
                        javax.servlet.http,
                        *;resolution:=optional
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Private-Package>
                        org.wso2.custom.authenticator.local.internal,
                    </Private-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                        !org.wso2.custom.authenticator.local.internal,
                        org.wso2.custom.authenticator.local.*;
                        version="1.0.0"
                    </Export-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>wso2-nexus</id>
        <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>wso2-maven2-repository</id>
        <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

**BasicCustomAuthenticator.java**

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.User;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityUtil;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.LocalApplicationAuthenticator;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.config.ConfigurationFacade;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.context.AuthenticationContext;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.InvalidCredentialsException;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.model.AuthenticatedUser;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreManager;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager;
import org.wso2.carbon.utils.multitenancy.MultitenantUtils;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Username Password based custom Authenticator
 */
public class BasicCustomAuthenticator extends AbstractApplicationAuthenticator implements LocalApplicationAuthenticator {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4345354156955223654L;
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(BasicCustomAuthenticator.class);


    @Override
    protected void initiateAuthenticationRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationContext context)
            throws AuthenticationFailedException {

        String loginPage = ConfigurationFacade.getInstance().getAuthenticationEndpointURL();//This is the
        // default WSO2 IS login page. If you can create your custom login page you can use
        // that instead.
        String queryParams =
                FrameworkUtils.getQueryStringWithFrameworkContextId(context.getQueryParams(),
                        context.getCallerSessionKey(),
                        context.getContextIdentifier());

        try {
            String retryParam = "";

            if (context.isRetrying()) {
                retryParam = "&authFailure=true&authFailureMsg=login.fail.message";
            }

            response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(loginPage + ("?" + queryParams)) +
                    "&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator:" + "LOCAL" + retryParam);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AuthenticationFailedException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to process the authentication response.
     * Inside here we check if this is a authentication request coming from oidc flow and then check if the user is
     * in the 'photoSharingRole'.
     */
    @Override
    protected void processAuthenticationResponse(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationContext context)
            throws AuthenticationFailedException {

        String username = request.getParameter(BasicCustomAuthenticatorConstants.USER_NAME);
        boolean isAuthenticated = true;
        context.setSubject(AuthenticatedUser.createLocalAuthenticatedUserFromSubjectIdentifier(username));
        boolean authorization = false;

        if(isAuthenticated) {
            if ("oidc".equalsIgnoreCase(context.getRequestType())) {
                // authorization only for openid connect requests
                try {
                    int tenantId = BasicCustomAuthenticatorServiceComponent.getRealmService().getTenantManager().
                            getTenantId(MultitenantUtils.getTenantDomain(username));
                    UserStoreManager userStoreManager = (UserStoreManager) BasicCustomAuthenticatorServiceComponent.getRealmService().
                            getTenantUserRealm(tenantId).getUserStoreManager();

                    // verify user is assigned to role
                    authorization = ((AbstractUserStoreManager) userStoreManager).isUserInRole(username, "photoSharingRole");
                } catch (UserStoreException e) {
                    log.error(e);
                } catch (org.wso2.carbon.user.api.UserStoreException e) {
                    log.error(e);
                }
            } else {
                // others scenarios are not verified.
                authorization = false;
            }

            if (!authorization) {
                log.error("user authorization is failed.");

                throw new InvalidCredentialsException("User authentication failed due to invalid credentials",
                        User.getUserFromUserName(username));

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean retryAuthenticationEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFriendlyName() {
        //Set the name to be displayed in local authenticator drop down lsit
        return BasicCustomAuthenticatorConstants.AUTHENTICATOR_FRIENDLY_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        String userName = httpServletRequest.getParameter(BasicCustomAuthenticatorConstants.USER_NAME);
        String password = httpServletRequest.getParameter(BasicCustomAuthenticatorConstants.PASSWORD);
        if (userName != null && password != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContextIdentifier(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        return httpServletRequest.getParameter("sessionDataKey");
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return BasicCustomAuthenticatorConstants.AUTHENTICATOR_NAME;
    }
}
```

**BasicCustomAuthenticatorServiceComponent**
public class BasicCustomAuthenticatorServiceComponent {

```
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(BasicCustomAuthenticatorServiceComponent.class);

private static RealmService realmService;

public static RealmService getRealmService() {
    return realmService;
}

protected void activate(ComponentContext ctxt) {
    try {
        BasicCustomAuthenticator basicCustomAuth = new BasicCustomAuthenticator();
        ctxt.getBundleContext().registerService(ApplicationAuthenticator.class.getName(), basicCustomAuth, null);
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.info("BasicCustomAuthenticator bundle is activated");
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log.error("BasicCustomAuthenticator bundle activation Failed", e);
    }
}

protected void deactivate(ComponentContext ctxt) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.info("BasicCustomAuthenticator bundle is deactivated");
    }
}

protected void unsetRealmService(RealmService realmService) {
    log.debug("UnSetting the Realm Service");
    BasicCustomAuthenticatorServiceComponent.realmService = null;
}

protected void setRealmService(RealmService realmService) {
    log.debug("Setting the Realm Service");
    BasicCustomAuthenticatorServiceComponent.realmService = realmService;
}
```

}

Comment: What's the version of IS you use? I guess there may be some OSGi service activation issues. If you add outcome of "Useful OSGi commands to debug" in https://anuradha-15.medium.com/lets-write-and-run-your-first-osgi-service-on-wso2-platform-482f6e5e3ea5 it would be easy to help

Comment: The version is 5.11.

Comment: Following is the output of debugging osgi> ss custom
"Framework is launched."


id      State       Bundle
514     ACTIVE      org.wso2.custom.authenticator.local_1.0.0
osgi> diag 514
org.wso2.custom.authenticator.local [514]
  No resolution report for the bundle.

Comment: osgi> b 514
org.wso2.custom.authenticator.local_1.0.0 [514]
  Id=514, Status=ACTIVE      Data Root=C:\Users\atejwani\Desktop\WSO2\wso2is-5.11.0\repository\components\default\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\514\data
  "No registered services."
  No services in use.
  No exported packages
  Imported packages
    javax.servlet; version="2.6.0" <tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.34.wso2v1 [542]>
    javax.servlet.http; version="2.6.0" <tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.34.wso2v1 [542]>
  No fragment bundles
  No required bundles

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna It would be great if you could share some suggestions

Comment: As per the output of the ` b 514` command, your ApplicationAuthenticator service is not registered. and exported packages defined in `maven-bundle-plugin` are not taken. There should be some mis-configs in your code. If you link the source code, we will be able to point out the issues. Otherwise, It would be easier for you to follow this sample authenticator https://github.com/wso2/samples-is/tree/master/authenticators/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sample.local.authenticator/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sample/local/authenticator

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna - I have attached the source code. Couldyou have a look at and share your thoughts. As I haven't made any customizations and was just following the steps mentioned in the link - https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/writing-a-custom-local-authenticator/#writing-a-custom-local-authenticator

Answer (score 0):

I have used same code as in the WSO2 Docs here.
Clone this code. Navigate to `org.wso2.custom.authenticator.local` and execute `mvn clean install` to build the code. Then `org.wso2.custom.authenticator.local-1.0.0.jar` will
e generated. https://github.com/AnuradhaSK/samples/tree/main/org.wso2.custom.authenticator.local

Copy it in to the `<IS_HOME>/repository/components/dropins` folder and restart the server.

When OSGi debugging is done, you can see service is properly registered.

[image]

Now, this custom authenticator is listing under local authenticators
[image]

Comment: yes on cloning it seems to  be working but following the documentation - https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/writing-a-custom-local-authenticator/#writing-a-custom-local-authenticator , I was facing issues